# craftbukkit.v1_15_R1.entity.CraftPlayer cannot be cast

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I'm not good at English, but i have to ask about this bug, because i can't fine it anywhere.

i am making minecraft plugin to back to place which player selelcted.

but i can't fix this bug...

it's whole error log

```
[10:57:29] [Server thread/INFO]: Player issued server command: /setposition
[10:57:29] [Server thread/ERROR]: null
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'setposition' in plugin Main v0.1
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:47) ~[Server.jar:git-Spigot-6de3d4b-fc24934]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:149) ~[Server.jar:git-Spigot-6de3d4b-fc24934]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_15_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:723) ~[Server.jar:git-Spigot-6de3d4b-fc24934]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1658) ~[Server.jar:git-Spigot-6de3d4b-fc24934]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1498) ~[Server.jar:git-Spigot-6de3d4b-fc24934]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:47) ~[Server.jar:git-Spigot-6de3d4b-fc24934]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:1) ~[Server.jar:git-Spigot-6de3d4b-fc24934]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.PlayerConnectionUtils.lambda$0(PlayerConnectionUtils.java:19) ~[Server.jar:git-Spigot-6de3d4b-fc24934]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.TickTask.run(SourceFile:18) [Server.jar:git-Spigot-6de3d4b-fc24934]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeTask(SourceFile:144) [Server.jar:git-Spigot-6de3d4b-fc24934]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.IAsyncTaskHandlerReentrant.executeTask(SourceFile:23) [Server.jar:git-Spigot-6de3d4b-fc24934]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeNext(SourceFile:118) [Server.jar:git-Spigot-6de3d4b-fc24934]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.ba(MinecraftServer.java:918) [Server.jar:git-Spigot-6de3d4b-fc24934]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.executeNext(MinecraftServer.java:911) [Server.jar:git-Spigot-6de3d4b-fc24934]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.IAsyncTaskHandler.awaitTasks(SourceFile:127) [Server.jar:git-Spigot-6de3d4b-fc24934]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.sleepForTick(MinecraftServer.java:895) [Server.jar:git-Spigot-6de3d4b-fc24934]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:828) [Server.jar:git-Spigot-6de3d4b-fc24934]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_15_R1.entity.CraftPlayer cannot be cast to package1.PlayerPosition
        at package1.SetPosition.onCommand(SetPosition.java:16) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) ~[Server.jar:git-Spigot-6de3d4b-fc24934]
        ... 17 more
```

it's back command

player can tp to selected place by setposition command

```
package package1;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import net.md_5.bungee.api.ChatColor;

public class Back implements CommandExecutor {

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args)
    {
        if(sender instanceof Player) {
            Player p = (Player) sender;
            PlayerPosition pp = (PlayerPosition) p;
            if(pp.location.equals(null)) {
                p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Set Your Position To Back First By Using SetPosition.");
                return false;

            }
            else 
            {

                p.teleport(pp.location);
            return true;

            }

        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

it's PlayerPosition class

this class extends Player

and a add location

```
package package1;

import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

public abstract class PlayerPosition implements Player {
    public Location location;

    PlayerPosition(Location l){
        this.location = l;
    }



}
```

and it's setposition command.

```
package package1;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import net.md_5.bungee.api.ChatColor;

public class SetPosition implements CommandExecutor {

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args)
    {
        if(sender instanceof Player) {
            Player p = (Player) sender;
            PlayerPosition pp = (PlayerPosition) p;

            pp.location = p.getLocation();

            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLUE + "Position Setting Complete.");
            return true;



        }   
    return false;

    }

}
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Player is an interface, not a class, so any class implementing Player interface must also implement all the methods in Player.

Example:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public void aMethod();
}
```

If you have a class that implements `myIntefrace` then your class must implement `aMethod`:

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    public void aMethod() {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

For more info refer to here: [Java Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

So if you wanted `PlayerPosition` to implement `Player` you would have to implement yourself a large number of methods contained in `Player` interface. Thus not recommended at all.

It is because of this that you cannot cast from `CraftPlayer` to `PlayerPosition`.

A workaround would be to save the player location in a `HashMap` on `/setposition` and to get it from it on `back`.

A solution to your problem could be the following one:

SetPosition.java:

```
public class SetPosition implements CommandExecutor {
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender theSender, Command command, String s, String[] strings) {
        if (theSender instanceof Player) {
            Player p = (Player) theSender;
            PluginCore.getInstance().setLocation(p, p.getLocation());
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLUE + "Position Setting Complete.");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Back.java:

```
public class Back implements CommandExecutor {
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender theSender, Command command, String s, String[] strings) {
        if (theSender instanceof Player) {
            Player p = (Player) theSender;
            Location location = PluginCore.getInstance().getLocation(p);
            if (location == null) {
                p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Set Your Position To Back First By Using SetPosition.");
            } else {
                p.teleport(location);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

PluginCore.java: (Main class)

```
public class PluginCore extends JavaPlugin {

    private static PluginCore instance;

    private HashMap<Player, Location> locations = new HashMap<Player, Location>();

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        instance = this;
        this.getCommand("back").setExecutor(new Back());
        this.getCommand("setposition").setExecutor(new SetPosition());
    }

    public static PluginCore getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public Location getLocations(Player p) {
        return locations.get(p);
    }

    public void setLocation(Player p, Location location) {
        this.locations.put(p, location);
    }
}
```

I hope it helped!